# Memory leak in rake task wtith ruby 2.0.0p353 and rails 4.0.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks

I've both googled and read other threads on the topic, and implemented all advice I could gather. But, I'm still having issues with too much memory being used (600MB+).

My users.rake file:

```
    namespace :users do
      desc "TODO"
      task sync_events: :environment do

        User.find_in_batches(batch_size: 5) do |users|
         users.each(&:sync_events)
        end
      end

    end
```

The sync_events method in user.rb model:

```
def sync_events

  unless  self.username.empty?


     # Make the request to swagger
    request = RestClient.get 'https://****************/event/findByUser/' + self.username + '?fromDate=' + 1.days.ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  + '&toDate=' + 10.days.from_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    json = JSON.parse request

    events = json['events']


    # We need to fetch the events from the DB or create them if they don't exists
    events.each do |event|

        # Find existing semester or create new
        semester_in_db = Semester.where(:name => event['semester'][0]['name']).first_or_create!

        # Find exisiting event, or create new one.
        event_in_db = Event.where(:ext_id => event['id']).first_or_create!(
            :title => event['title'], 
            :description => event['description'],
            :begin => Time.parse(event['begin']),
            :end => Time.parse(event['end']),
            :semester_id => semester_in_db.id
            )


        # Check if lectureres/users exist, or create new, and add them to the event
        event['lecturer'].each do |lecturer|

          # We only want to do this for users with emails - valid users
          if lecturer["email"].length > 5

            user = User.where(:username => lecturer['username']).first_or_create!(
                :email => lecturer['username'] + '@feil.no', 
                  :altEmail => lecturer['email'],
                :password => 'password', 
                :password_confirmation => 'password',
                :first_name => lecturer['firstname'],
                :last_name => lecturer['lastname'],
                  :identity =>  lecturer['firstname'] + ' ' +  lecturer['lastname']
                )
            #connect lecturer to event
            event_in_db.users << user unless event_in_db.user_ids.include?(user.id)

            #Add role
            user.add_role :lecturer, event_in_db

            #try to sync email, because sometimes email is not formatted correctly
            begin
              user.email = lecturer['email']
              user.save!
            rescue
              e = Error.new
              e.body =  lecturer['email']
              e.save
            end

          end

        end

        # Added student user
        event_in_db.users << self unless event_in_db.user_ids.include?(self.id)

        # add role student, unless lecturer
        self.add_role :student, event_in_db unless self.has_role? :lecturer, event_in_db

      end

    end

  end
```

You can probably see that I'm not a trained ruby developer. This code is headed for some major refactoring. But, in the mean time, I can't see why it's hogging all my memory. I've got about 500+ users in the DB. Eventually, my rake task gets killed.

As you can see, I'm already using find_in_batches instead of all. I've also converted all instance variables to local variables.

What more can I do?

Comment: I'd start with commenting out everything in `sync_events` and then slowly adding code bit by bit while observing the used memory.

Comment: Thanks. 

But, where / how would I even start?

Comment: First remove everything from the method. Run the rake task and look at the used memory. Is it still at 600MB? then the problem is not in your code. If it is lower, start by adding only the request and JSON parsing back. Observer the memory footprint again. Then in our `events.each` block gain only add parts of code one at a time, and observe.

Comment: I did what you said. But I couldn't find the culprit. I reran the old code, and guess what? No memory leak anymore. Gone, just gone. Magically. Hmm...